# Display yellow warning message in console

Tags: javascript, warnings, console.log

I want to show a warning message in the Chrome console, like the highlighted item in this screenshot:

[image: The message has a pale, yellow background with brown text and is prefaced with a yellow warning triangle.]

`console.log(message)` displays a normal white message.

`console.error(message)` creates an error message.

But using `console.warning(message)` returns `Uncaught TypeError: console.warning is not a function.`

So is there any way to present a console warning for JavaScript?

It should be like this:

```js
(function() {
  var newbgcolor = document.getElementById('mycolor').value;
  document.getElementById('output').style.backgroundColor = newbgcolor;
});

function update() {
  var mycolorvalue = document.getElementById('mycolor').value;
  if (mycolorvalue != "#000000") {
    document.getElementById('output').style.backgroundColor = mycolorvalue;
  } else {
    console.warning("Text will be hard to read!"); // <-- error happens
  }
}
```

```css
#output {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Background color:</p>
  <input type="color" id="mycolor" value="#00ffff" oninput="update()" />
  <p id="output">You will see the change here.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

But it doesn't work. How do I do this?

**Edit**: I could use custom CSS!

```js
console.log(
  "%c Foo",
  "display:block;width:100%;background-color: #332B00;color:#F2AB26;"
);
```

But it just doesn't look right:
[image: failed attempt]

Comment: `console.warn` is what you're looking for not `console.warning`.

Comment: Just a tip since you have put much effort into asking this question although it has a very simple answer. Assuming you are new to programming, in a programming problem like this, searching "how to console log warning message in js" would definitely give you the answer, saving you the time of asking a question of which the answer is very well known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `console.warn` method instead of `console.warning`.

### Example

```js
console.warn("A sample warning message!");
```

### Reference

Here's a resource containing a full list of available console methods:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#methods